# Diff Between p[i] , i[p] and *(p+i) , *(i+p) in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I want to know the Difference between below four terms in **C/C++:**

1. p[i]
2. i[p]
3. *(p+i)
4. *(i+p)

Where p is Array, i is loop current index.

Comment: I think this same question was asked yesterday.

Comment: can you provide the link I have searched but didn't get

Comment: in short they are same way of indicating i'th element of array p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p+i)`, as per the standard definition.  Because addition is commutative, `*(p+i)` is the same as `*(i+p)`.  And as per the rule previously stated, `*(i+p)` is equivalent to `i[p]`.

So, they are all the same.

Note that this only applies to built-in operators *(i.e. operators applied to built-in types)*. User defined operators (both `[]` and `+`) do not have to follow these rules.

Comment: _"Because addition is commutative"_ it's not really an explanation for this, I would say that is because the way _pointer arithmetic_ works; the addition itself it's part of an expression but doesn't really explain what's going on.

Comment: @user2485710 It explains exactly what is going on.  It is a mathematical operation (addition).  Order of operands does not matter for addition.

Comment: @ZacHowland nope, think about removing the addition and putting a multiplication in it. it's just a math operation with no special meaning, it's not the core of what it's happening nor it's part of a good explanation.

Comment: @user2485710: *"I would say that is because the way pointer arithmetic works"* -- And I would say *that* doesn't explain anything. I stand by my answer as a correct explanation of what is going on.

Comment: @user2485710 Whether it is addition or multiplication, it matters not.  For this question, it is addition, and it is the same for all 4 ways described in the OP's question - and yes, it **is** the core of what is happening.

Comment: I still think that programming is different from _math 101_

Answer (score 2):

1. This accesses the (i + 1)-th element of an array pointed to by `p`.  This can either be a static array or a dynamic array - in either case, `p` points to the first element (0).
2. This is a bad way to write the same thing and should never be used in real code.  It would result in treating `i` as a pointer to an array and `p` as an index.  Mathematically, it would work out to the be the same memory location, but as written, I would be surprised if it compiles (though, it does as shown in the example - but it is still a poor way to structure code as it goes against the normal convention).
3. This is the same as #1
4. Also the same as #1

You can see them all [here](http://ideone.com/wvMfGf)

Comment: The second one is actually adding the value of p (address of array) to the integer i, right?.

Comment: Honestly, The idea that `p[i] = *(p+i)` always confuses me. what if `sizeof(*p)` is something large like `64`? I always thought that `p[i] = *(p + i*sizeof(*p))`

Comment: @sajas Yes, it would be dereferencing an array `i` at offset `p` (which works out to the correct memory location mathematically - and compiles with gcc, surprisingly).

Comment: #point 2 -> Yes it is compiling successfully...And return same result as p[i].

Comment: @mebob The sizeof is implied with the arithmetic.

Comment: @ZacHowland Ah, that is the missing link for me. Is the same true for C? Or just C++? What could I do to get just a plain byte offset, if I ever needed one?

Comment: @Zac, there is no array `i` in this scenario, and it should come as no surprise that GCC (or any other C compiler) accepts it, given it's perfectly valid C code.

Comment: @mebob Yes, this is the same for C.

Comment: @RobKennedy I did not state it was invalid, just that it was a poor way to write it.  And given that the type for `i` is `int`, and not `int[]` or `int*`, it is kind of surprising that a strongly typed language doesn't complain about it (even though the math works out either way).

Comment: I feel like such a moron. I've wasted so much time writing the `i*sizeof(...)` statement in the past.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest you thought it was invalid. But why would you be surprised that a C compiler accepts C code? Did you instead mean to express surprise that the standards *said* it was valid in the first place? That's more understandable. I don't think it was constructed as a primary goal, though. Rather, it was a natural consequence of the other rules (expansion of bracket notation, and commutativity of addition), and wasn't worth expressly disallowing.

Comment: @RobKennedy "Did you instead mean to express surprise that the standards said it was valid in the first place?" <-- Yes.  Though, I understand why it is allowed when it is converted to the dereferencing notation, it still is rather odd looking.

Answer (score 0):

p[i] means you are access the **i+1** th element of the array **p**.

*(p+i) means you are defining a pointer *p, and accessing the contents of a memory location away from p by i times the size of the data that p points to.

(Again this means the same in case of array p[i], just adding the additional meaning to this when *explicitly* using pointer).

Assume that p is a **pointer to int** and that size of int is 4 bytes, then p+i points to a memory location **x** +4*i. where **x** is the memory location pointed to by **p**. Hence *(p+i) is used to access the **contents** of that memory location.

**EDIT:** and i[p] and*(i+p) is the same as p[i] (as I learnt just now) :)

Comment: In p[i] and i[p] p is array and i is a loop index...Both array are not diffrent

Comment: It would actually be accessing the `(i + 1)-th` element as p[0] would be accessing the first (1) element.

Answer (score 0):

You declare an Array `arr[n]`,

1. `arr` `--->` base address of the array and `n` is the `offset`.
2. `arr[n]` `--->` accessing the `n`th element from the array or better `n` offset from the base address
3. `*(arr + n)` == `*(n + arr)` adding `n` offset to the base address to get the element.
4. `n[arr]` == just another way of accessing the array , "associative property"

Comment: I'm not sure where the associative property comes into this. There are only two operands.